# Wordpress delte watermark in footer with css

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

I am using a Wordpress Template and I want to change/delete the watermark which is in the footer.

[image]

In the template I cannot do this so I tried it with css. I tried it with:

```css
footer p designed-by { display: none;
}
```

The class where the watermark is in:

[image]

Comment: Did you pay to remove it?

Comment: It´s a premium template yes, so I should be able to remove it.

Comment: The proper selector would be `footer p.designed-by`

Comment: If its premium, you should be able to do change it/delete it in your theme options, that is where I delete on my premium themes

Comment: jo08691 thanks man! That worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target the `designed-by` class, your selector needs to be writen as
`.designed-by` (You’re missing a period.)

Comment: That works! Thank you very much.